# Recursive function and add to an array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I need recursive function to add element into an array. This is my code:

```
$array_final = array();
$counter = 1;

function get_previuos_levels($first_available_place_x, $first_available_place_y, $array_final , $counter) {
                
    $new_x = $first_available_place_x-1;
                
    $devider = $first_available_place_y/3;
    $new_y = ceil($devider);

    //echo $new_x;
    //echo '<br>';
    //echo $new_y;

        if($new_x > 1) {
            $array_final['value'][$counter] = $new_x . ' - ' . $new_y;
            $counter++;
                            
            get_previuos_levels($new_x, $new_y, $array_final , $counter);
                            
                            
        }


        return $array_final;
        
}
        
$result = get_previuos_levels(3, 5, $array_final , $counter);
        
    

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result );
echo '</pre>';
```

Basically, if I echo $new_x and $new_y, I get what I'm expecting.
Problem is my $result array, it gives me only first item (2 -2) but second is missing (1 -1). I guess problem is with adding item into array but cannot find the problem.

Comment: Your inner call needs to be `$array_final = get_previuos_levels($new_x, $new_y, $array_final , $counter);`. Otherwise, you're just throwing away any changes that it makes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recursively add elements to array and return new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159091/recursively-add-elements-to-array-and-return-new-array)

Comment: also you can use array_walk_recursive

Comment: I'm getting these values dynamically from database and add to inner function: $result = get_previuos_levels($first_available_place_x, $first_available_place_y, $array_final , $counter);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution if somebody need.

```
    $array_final = array();
    $counter = 1;
    
    
     function get_previuos_levels($first_available_place_x, $first_available_place_y) {
         
            $new_x = $first_available_place_x-1;
                
            $devider = $first_available_place_y/3;
            $new_y = ceil($devider);
            
            $array_key = 1;
            
            for($value = $new_x; $value > 0; $value--) {
                 $array_final['x_coor'][$array_key] = $value;
                 $array_final['y_coor'][$array_key] = $new_y;
                 
                 
                $devider = $new_y/3;
                $new_y = ceil($devider);
                 
                $array_key++;
                 
                 
            }
            return $array_final;
    }
        
        
    $result = get_previuos_levels($first_available_place_x, $first_available_place_y);  
        
        
        
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
```